# SingalR hub method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have table with products, and I want to display in real-time votes amount for each product using SignalR. I don't know why $.connection.hub.start() inside jquery "each" method don't work properly. I tried put $('td').each function inside $.connection.hub.start(), but then strange things happens when debugging method in Hub   :

```
<div class="products">
    <table class="tableClass">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Products)
                {
                    <td class="@item.Id">
                        <span class="productId" hidden="hidden">@item.Id</span>
                        <img src="~/Images/imageNotFound.png" style="max-width: 420px; max-height: 420px" />
                        <span>@item.Name</span>
                        @*@Html.ActionLink("Vote", "AddVote", new { productId = item.Id }, new { type = "button" })*@
                        <input type="button" class="voteBtn" title="Vote" value="Vote" itemid="@item.Id" />
                        <br />
                        <span class="votesAmount"></span>
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <span class="messageClass" style="color:red;"></span>
</div>
```

Hub:

```
public void VotesAmount(int productId, string className)
{
    GetVotesAmountResponse response = VoteService.GetVotesAmount(new GetVotesAmountRequest() { ProductId = productId });
    int votesAmount = 0;
    if (response.Status == true)
    {
        votesAmount = response.Amount;
        Clients.Caller.getVotesAmount(votesAmount, className);
    }
    else
    {
        Clients.Caller.getVotesAmount(votesAmount, className); 
    }
}
```

Script in view:

```
vote.client.getVotesAmount = function (votesAmount, className) {
    $('td.'+className).find('span.votesAmount').text('VotesAmount: ' + votesAmount + ' ProductID:' + productId);
};

$('td').each(function () {
   $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
   vote.server.votesAmount($(this).find('.productId').text(), $(this).attr('class'));
   });
})
```

I tried this too (not working though):

```
$.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    $('td').each(function () {
        vote.server.votesAmount($(this).find('.productId').text(), $(this).attr('class'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Because that is not the way it works, you should start the connection only once.

Comment: I added different way to do this (I updated text above), but it still doesn't work properly. I need to get votes amount from db for each product, and display it in proper span inside <td>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second option should work. Problem is with the product id in the callback method.

```
vote.client.getVotesAmount = function (votesAmount, className) {
$('td.'+className).find('span.votesAmount').text('VotesAmount: ' + votesAmount +
```

**'ProductID:' + productId);**
    };

productid variable is not available here inside this method. So I removed that and it worked. Better you can assign value or remove that.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I was really close to make this work, but your answer was really helpfull. Thanks one more time